# jQuery.promise locking user on page

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

Here is the situation. I have a long running database operation that the user is able to initiate from the web application. I need to inform them when the operation finishes. The jQuery promise with ajax looked very good and in my little test page I have it working except that it seems to lock them on that page until the request completes or fails. Perhaps I am coding it incorrectly - here is my test code:

The jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.Process = function () {
 var promise = $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "MyPage.aspx/MyTest",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: "{}",
     dataType: "json"
 });
 promise.done(function () { alert("Import completed."); });
 promise.fail(function () { alert("Import failed"); });
 promise.always(function () { alert("Attempt complete"); }); 
};
```

The test service:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function MyTest() As String
Dim strReturn As String = String.Empty

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000) 'To test long response

Return strReturn
End Function
```

Once they execute this code they are locked until it completes or finishes successfully.

Comment: If ajax is async, shouldn't be the case

Comment: async: true is the default for ajax in jQuery but I did try adding that attribute anyway - no change.

Comment: "I have it working except that it seems to lock them on that page" So what make you think it locks UI?

Comment: Because if I click on menu items on the page nothing happens until the notification from the promise comes back (one of the alerts) - then the click function happens. It is not acting like an async operation.

Comment: i'm unable to reproduce it, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Ez876/

Comment: do the functions happen all at once, or do they only happen if you "click" after the operation completes

Comment: @A. Wolff - Yes - that is interesting - does not work like that on my page. The secondary button click is delayed until the promise answers.

Comment: @ Kevin B  - there are separate buttons that initiate the long running process and for other items on the page

Comment: that's not what i'm asking. Your clicks on the menu.. When you click and nothing happens, do they automatically happen once the operation is complete, or do you have to re-click them.

Comment: Yes - the clicked item automatically happens once the long running operation is complete